# Could we prove the rank $=$ # of rows $\rightarrow$ the system of linear equation is consistent deducitvely?

Tags: linear-algebra, alternative-proof

Proof subject: the rank $=$ # of rows $\rightarrow$ the system of linear equation(SLE) is consistent

Description:

1. I want to prove this deductively but not inductively.
2. I have read the proof of a SLE is consistent $\iff$ rank$([\textbf {A}])=$ rank$([\textbf{A}|~\textbf{b}])$. It uses a concept of dimension. Like, It's in the dimension of $\textbf A$, so the system must be consistent because $\textbf b$ is image of $T_\textbf A$. But I want other proofs without this dimension thing. or I want someone could give a proof unfolding this relation between dimension and consistency because for what I've concerned, it's not straightforward enough as a proof by just saying if it's in the dimension of $\textbf A$, then blablabla....
3. I have read a proof like: all of situation where the SLE is inconsistent must have a last zero row after eliminated into reduced Echelon Form. It's a more inductive way and definitely not what I want.

Comment: See [Consistency od of System of Linear Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Consistency)

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132098/proving-a-linear-system-a-bfx-bfb-is-consistent-iff-the-rank-of-a)

Comment: What's your definition of rank?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I saw this one before. It's quite a brilliant and neat proof by *Marc van Leeuwen*. Somehow, it's related to the dimension concept.

Comment: @egreg It's the dimension of the space spanned by the columns of the coefficient matrix of a SLE.

Comment: @Shih-YuYang So how can you think of proving the statement without mentioning dimension?

Comment: First: start writing all the relevant definitions. Second: write the precise (and correct) statement of the theorem to be proved.

Comment: According to the linked post, we have something like: "if $\text {Rank}(A \mid b) = \text {Rank}(A)$, then $\text {Cons}(A \mid b)$"

Comment: @egreg Yeah. I thought that way too. It can't happen without dimension. Maybe my question is vague even to myself. I have to clarify it later.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I understand what you try to express: rank$(\textbf A)=$ # of rows of $\textbf A\rightarrow$ rank$([\textbf A|\textbf b])=$ rank$(\textbf A)$, then implies consistency.

Comment: As I said in the post, I read nearly all proofs on the site except for those I can't easily reach with regular keyword. I here found a lot interested answers and questions before, so I just thought I might get some inspiration, or maybe there was someone who had the same thoughts as I did. And I now know my question is not concrete enough. I will read some materials again and to specify my question again.

Comment: Thank you for getting down to it with me.